# How do I change which variable is called? (specifically Objects)

Tags: python, class, variables, instance-variables, renpy

I am trying to create a little monster-collection game with the ability to collect multiple monsters of the same type with variable stats between them. The issue I'm having is that I don't know how to make an object that doesn't overwrite the previous one! The previous object made, so if I caught a Slime, five minutes later I could catch a goblin...which overwrites my Slime.

It will be done within Renpy if that changes things

The only thing I can think of is a long drawn out If statement going through each number to see if it the one I want, but that seems so messy especially since I'd need to go through it every time I want to reference . I've tried looking things up online but none of the tutorials seem to touch this aspect.

```
init python:
    class Monster:
        def __init__(self, species, hp, slot)
            self.type = species
            self.health = hp
            self.is = slot

label start:
    $ Slot1 = Monster("Null", 0, 2)
    $ Slot2 = Monster("Null", 0, 2)
    $ Slot3 = Monster("Null", 0, 3)
    ...continue code

label Caught:
    #Assume Species and HP are assigned before calling this label)
    $ X = 1
    $ Counter = 0
    while Counter = 0
        if Slot[X].slot = 1:
            $ X += 1
        elseif Slot[X].slot = 3:
            "You have too many Monsters"
            $ Counter = 1
        else:
            $ Slot[X] = Monster(Species, HP, 1)
```

What code do I need to do to make this work? This should increment through them until it finds an open slot assuming my little made-up [X] could actually modify the variable being created/called.

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't know how to make an object that doesn't overwrite the previous one!"? You are on the last row of the code snippet creating a new instance, so of course it will overwrite your previous instance of the object

Comment: you should use `==` not `=` in your `if/elseif` statements

Comment: No I know that, I want to specify which variable is made. I don't want to make Slot1, then five minutes later make Slot1, overwriting the last monster caught.

Comment: Why don't you use a list of Monsters? Then you can just append the new one.